# dask dataframe from read_csv using python engine unreliable behaviour

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

my data is a 10GB file with the following format:

```
[ 1234567890 ][ 2020052701020201 ][ value1 ][ value2 ][ key3 = value3 ]...[ keyn = valuen ]
```

Note:

1. There could be any number of [ key = value ] blocks.
2. chars `[` and `]` are in the values themselves, for eg: `[ hello = wo[rld] ]`
3. I have no control over the abinput file, except i can change / handle it in my script.
4. I only need a few of the columns, however they have chars `[` and `]` in the values.

In my simple `for line in f:` function, i can split by `' ][ '` pattern. however given the size of the file, dask is very lucrative.

I know that with `engine='c'` i cannot have multichar separator, but switching to `engine='python'` is resulting in unpredictable results. here is an example:

```py
def init_ddf(filename):
    return ddf.read_csv(
        filename,
        blocksize="1GB",
        sep="]",
        usecols=[1, 8],
        na_filter=False,
        names=["hello", World" ],
        engine="c",
    )
```

The above code as expected results in `ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 25 and found 24`. This error is very hard to reproduce since it only happens due to some specific lines that are hard to identify for me. It doesnt happen every time there are more columns. So in the above function i changed: `engine="python"` and `sep=" \]\[ "`. This works on a small sample data i test with. but in the 10G file, i get the following unpredictable behaviour:

```py
def init_pyddf(filename, usecols, names):
    return ddf.read_csv(
        filename,
        blocksize="1GB",
        sep=" \]\[ ",
        usecols=usecols,
        na_filter=False,
        names=names,
        engine="python",
    )
```

```py
In [50]: !head   /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
==> /tmp/foo <==
[ 1234567890 ][ 2020052701020201 ][ value1 ][ value2 ][ key3 = value3 ][ keyn = valuen ]
[ 1590471107 ][ 20200526T0731460 ][ THEOQQ ][ e = CL ][ Even = 175134 ][ rded = a12344 ][ blah = INVALID ][ N = T ][ ED = 13606 ]                       

==> /tmp/bar <==
[ 1234567890 ][ 2020052701020201 ][ value1 ][ value2 ][ key3 = value3 ][ keyn = valuen ]
[ 1590471107 ][ 20200526T0731460 ][ THEOQQ ][ e = CL ][ Even = 175134 ][ rded = a12344 ]

In [51]: init_pyddf("/tmp/foo", [1,2], ["time", "name"]).compute()
Out[51]: 
                                               time             name
[ 1234567890 2020052701020201 value1  key3 = value3  keyn = valuen ]
[ 1590471107 20200526T0731460 THEOQQ  Even = 175134    rded = a12344

In [52]: init_pyddf("/tmp/bar", [1,2], ["time", "name"]).compute()
Out[52]: 
               time    name
0  2020052701020201  value1
1  20200526T0731460  THEOQQ
```

Some more examples:

```py
In [110]: !cat /tmp/dummy
[ 0 ][ 000000000000000000000000000 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]
[ 1 ][ 20200526T073146.901861+0200 ][ T ][ E ][ E ][ F ][ W ][ N ][ E ][ E ][ 5 ]

In [111]: init_pyddf("/tmp/dummy", [1,7], ["time", "name"]).compute().head()
Out[111]: 
    time name
[ 0    0    0
[ 1    T    E

In [112]: !cat /tmp/dummy
[ 0 ][ 000000000000000000000000000 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]
[ 1 ][ 20200526T073146.901861+0200 ][ T ][ E ][ E ][ F ][ W ][ N ][ E ][ E ]

In [113]: init_pyddf("/tmp/dummy", [1,7], ["time", "name"]).compute().head()
Out[113]: 
                          time name
0  000000000000000000000000000    0
1  20200526T073146.901861+0200    N

In [119]: !cat /tmp/dummy
[ 0 ][ 000000000000000 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]
[ 1 ][ 20200526T073146 ][ T ][ D ][ F ][ W ][ e ][ E ][ E ][ I ][ T ][ T ][ S ][ S ][ B ][ A ][ E ][ F ][ S ][ P][ T = Y ][ 0 ]

In [120]: init_pyddf("/tmp/dummy", [1,7], ["time", "name"]).compute()
Out[120]: 
                                           time  name
[ 0 000000000000000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ] NaN  None  None
[ 1 20200526T073146 T D F W e E E I   T       S     S
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a more complex text-based file format you might first start with Dask Bag, use normal Python functions to generate python dictionaries, and then convert that Bag into a Dask Dataframe with the `to_dataframe` method.

```
import dask.bag

b = dask.bag.read_text("my-files.*.txt")

def parse(line: str) -> dict:
    ...

records = b.map(parse)
df = b.to_dataframe()
```